# Socket KeepAlive Units

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Based on some posts here, I have written the following simple method for setting my Socket KeepAlive, and it seems to work. After I unplug my ethernet cable to break connectivity between two services, my network library can handle the 0-bytes-transferred on the SocketAsyncEventArgs Completed event and fire up a Disconnected event.

But for some reason, I need to use hundredths of a second instead of milliseconds. All the documentation I can find on this seems to indicate I should use milliseconds.

(edit) I have now verified that the bytes returned match with these other two methods:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117557/Set-Keep-Alive-Values

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35dfb50e-1e14-40c1-af01-f359be4d6a02/how-to-set-socket-keep-alive-timeinterval-values

(edit) I have also WireSharked this and can verify that the KeepAlives are going out every 5 seconds when the interval is set to 500.

What gives??? Did something break in the latest version of .NET?

```
private static byte[] GetKeepAliveOption(bool isEnabled, int keepAliveTime, int keepAliveInterval)
{
    //time and interval are in hundredths of a second to work properly
    //12 keepalive bytes, 1st 4 for enabled, next 4 for time, next 4 for interval
    byte[] bytes = new byte[12];

    if (isEnabled)
    {
        bytes[0] = 1;
    }

    byte[] keepAliveTimeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(KeepAliveTime);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(keepAliveTimeBytes, 0, bytes, 4, 4);

    byte[] keepAliveIntervalBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(KeepAliveInterval);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(keepAliveIntervalBytes, 0, bytes, 8, 4);

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Your function is doing two things. Please show only relevant code. Extract the "tcp_keepalive struct creation code" (all of it except the `socket.IOControl()` call) into a separate method with three parameters (`enabled`, `time`, `interval`) which returns a `byte[]` and show the expected and actual output for the required values. This way you can test and verify the bytes contain what you expect them to contain, before passing them to IOControl.

Comment: Thanks for the comment CodeCaster. Sorry, I was actually just trying to simplify the method, but it certainly never hurts to use good programming practice and do some unit testing ;) I have altered the method slightly, and edited the post to reflect the testing I did. My conclusion? The KeepAlive now requires Hundredths of a second, not milliseconds.

Comment: You haven't really cited any authoritative sources that suggest that the value was ever actually milliseconds.  I think it's much more likely that these two articles you found are incorrect than that this behavior changed suddenly.

Comment: Good point Edward, sorry I am new to this and obviously have made assumptions. The method in question is socket.IOControl, which takes bytes, the best I could find were some articles on MSDN like this: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and this: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, which indicate the use of milliseconds.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the wild-goose chase, I can answer my own question. In the end it was my misunderstanding of the parameters. Based on the documentation in my comment above, I can account for the factor of 10. The keepalivetime parameter is how many mils of silence before sending a keepalive. The keepalive interval is how long to wait without an ack to the keepalive message, before sending a re-transmission probe. On Windows 7, re-transmission probes is fixed at 10, so when I set both keepalive params to 500, it was taking 500 + 10*500 mils before identifying a disconnect, or about 5.5 seconds.

Comment: I have verified all this in wireshark (I must have setup my wireshark filter wrong in earlier tests). By the way, windows server versions default to 5 re-transmission probes, but are configurable in a couple registry settings. In the end, if you want to know within 5 seconds when the remote endpoint is not responding, set keepalives to 2500, 250 (on a Windows 7 machine).

Comment: @Chi_Town_Don please answer your own question for other people that have the same doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question in the comments. Sorry it's my first post, I should have done so in an Answer like this.

The gist of this is understanding the parameters:

- KeepAliveTime is the interval between sending KeepAlive messages.
- KeepAliveInterval is the interval between sending re-transmission probes when the initial KeepAlive message has NOT been acked.